# How to create reversed square brackets and curly brackets using forest?

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

Using the forest package, I've been building a tree that grows from west to east and uses square brackets and curly brackets to connect parents and children. Is it possible to have any bracket connecting two children from different parents?
This is the code I have right now:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    for tree={
        align=left, 
        grow=0,
        reversed,
        parent anchor=east,
        child anchor=west,
        edge path={
            \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}](!u.parent anchor) -- +(5pt,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};},
        anchor=west, 
        }
[vestuário
    [frio]
    [calor
        [praia, edge=rounded corners
            [\\, edge=rounded corners
                [ggggggg]
                [hhhhhhhhhh]
            ]
            [\\, edge=rounded corners,
                [iiiiiiiii \\ \scriptsize $\searrow$ Ator+Meta; \\ \scriptsize \ \ \ \ Ator] 
                [jjjjjjjj]
        ]
        ]
        [eeeeeee, no edge] 
        [fffffffff, edge=rounded corners
            [kkkk]
            [llllllllllll]
        ]
    ]
    [\ \ \ \ \ \ ,name=arc01] 
]
\draw
    []([xshift=-5pt]arc01)
  arc[start angle=90,end angle=0,
  radius=0.5cm] 
  node [pos=1.2]{\textit{*}}; 
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

This is the result I want:

[image]

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in solution. You could just name the nodes h, i, j and l and draw the rest manually with TikZ just like you did with the *.

Answer (score 4):

There is no non-hackish way to do this in `forest`. The simplest would be to just annotate in Ti*k*Z after the fact. If you want more in-`forest` stuff, you run into complications because switching growth through 180 isn't possible.

```
\documentclass{standalone}% ref.: ateb JJSilva https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/651224/ i ei chwestiwn/gwestiwn ei hunain https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/651136/ 
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/690712/
\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}
\forestset{%
  declare keylist={my icky keys}{},
  declare keylist register={annotated stages},
  declare boolean={adjuster}{0},
  declare toks={adjustment relative}{},
  adjust to me/.style={%
    adjuster,
    adjustment relative=#1,
  },
  icky keys/.style={
    paint the town/.style={red, edge=red, before computing xy={l:=2}},
    my icky keys={%
      for tree={
        if adjuster={
          typeout/.option=name,
          tempdima/.option=x,
          tempdima-/.process={Ow+O}{adjustment relative}{!{name=##1}.x},
          tempdimb/.option=y,
          tempdimb-/.process={Ow+O}{adjustment relative}{!{name=##1}.y},
          for name/.process={O}{adjustment relative}{for tree={x+/.register=tempdima,y+/.register=tempdimb}},
        }{},
      },
    },
  },
  annotated stages={% customised definition of stages
    for root'={% nothing is removed from the standard forest definition - we only change it by adding to it
      process keylist register=default preamble,
      process keylist register=preamble,
    },
    process keylist=given options,
    process keylist=before typesetting nodes,
    typeset nodes stage,
    process keylist=before packing,
    pack stage,
    process keylist=before computing xy,
    compute xy stage,
    % addition
    process keylist=my icky keys,
    process keylist=before drawing tree,
    draw tree stage,
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  (%
    stages/.register=annotated stages,
  )%
  icky keys,
  for tree={
    forked edge,
    anchor=west, 
  },
  [,phantom,s sep=1cm
    [vestuário, for tree={grow=east}
      [frio]
      [calor
        [praia, edge=rounded corners
          [,  s sep:=3 
            [balde, name=f5, 
            ]
            [, phantom,    
              before computing xy={
                l*=2,
              }
              [, adjust to me=p7, for tree={grow=west, paint the town}, 
                [,name=p5, edge=rounded corners, tikz+={\draw [red] (f6.parent anchor) -- (.center);}]
                [,name=p6, edge=rounded corners, tikz+={\draw [red] (f5.parent anchor) -- (.center);}]
              ]
            ]
            [pá, name=f6]
          ]
          [
            [areia, name=f2, tikz+={\draw [red] (.parent anchor) -| (p20.child anchor) |- (f1.parent anchor);}]
            [castelo
              [, coordinate, no edge, name=p20
                [, coordinate, edge={->}, for tree={paint the town}, for children={fork sep'=0pt}, name=p3, 
                  [a]
                  [b]
                ]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
        [deserto, no edge
        ]
        [Ásia, edge=rounded corners
          [norte]
          [sul, name=f1]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [, coordinate, name=p7, for tree={grow=east, paint the town}
      [, coordinate, edge={->}, for children={fork sep'=0pt}
        [x]
        [y]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  (%
    stages/.register=annotated stages,
  )%
  icky keys,
  for tree={
    forked edge,
    anchor=west, 
    grow'=0,
    align=left,
    if={>Ow+P{n children}{isodd(#1)}}{%
      for n/.process={Ow+P{n children}{int((#1+1)/2)} {calign with current edge}  },
    }{},
  },
  [, phantom, s sep'=10mm
    [vestuário
      [frio]
      [calor
          [praia, edge=rounded corners
              [, edge=rounded corners
                  [ggggggg]
                  [hhhhhhhhhh, name=f2, tikz+={\draw [red] (.parent anchor) -- (p20 |- .parent anchor) |- (f1.20 -| f1.70);}]
              ]
              [, phantom, before computing xy={
                  l*=2.5,
                }
                [, coordinate, adjust to me=p20, tier=align adjusters, for tree={grow=west}, paint the town]
              ]
              [, edge=rounded corners,
                  [iiiiiiiii \\ \scriptsize $\searrow$ Ator+Meta; \\ \scriptsize \ \ \ \ Ator, name=f1] 
                  [jjjjjjjj, name=f6]
          ]
          ]
          [eeeeeee, no edge] 
          [fffffffff, edge=rounded corners
              [kkkk 
                [, phantom, before computing xy={
                  l*=2,
                }
                  [, coordinate, adjust to me=p7, tier=align adjusters, for tree={grow=west, paint the town}
                    [,name=p5, edge=rounded corners, tikz+={\draw [red] (f6.parent anchor) -- (.center);}]
                    [,name=p6, edge=rounded corners, tikz+={\draw [red] (f5.parent anchor) -- (.center);}]
                  ]
                ]
              ]
              [llllllllllll,name=f5]
          ]
      ]
      [,name=arc01]
    ]
    [, coordinate, name=p7, for tree={grow=east, paint the town}
      [, coordinate, edge={->}, for children={fork sep'=0pt}
        [x]
        [y]
      ]
    ]
    [, coordinate, no edge, name=p20
      [, coordinate, edge={->}, for tree={paint the town}, for children={fork sep'=0pt}, name=p3, 
        [a]
        [b]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  \draw ([xshift=5pt]arc01)
  arc [start angle=90,end angle=0,radius=0.5cm] 
  node [pos=1.2]{\textit{*}}; 
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: adjusted trees]

If I'd known how long this would take, I never would have started. I forgot how much I've forgotten.

[And if I'd known I'd edit it as well, I probably wouldn't have finished either.]

Answer (score 3):

This is the best I got. I don't know how to arrange the red trees to have something compact just like the image in the the question.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    for tree={
        forked edge,
        anchor=west, 
        }
[,phantom,s sep=1cm
[vestuário, for tree={grow=east}
    [frio]
    [calor
        [praia, edge=rounded corners
            [
                [balde, name=f5]
                [pá, name=f6]
            ]
            [
                [areia, name=f2]
                [castelo]
            ]
        ]
        [deserto, no edge
        ]
        [Ásia, edge=rounded corners
            [norte]
            [sul, name=f1]
        ]
    ]
]
[,for tree={grow=west, edge=red}, name=f3
[,name=p1]
[,name=p2]
]
[,for tree={grow=east, edge=red}, name=p3
[a, red]
[b, red]
]
[,for tree={grow=west, edge=red}, name=f7
[,name=p5, edge=rounded corners]
[,name=p6, edge=rounded corners]
]
[,for tree={grow=east, edge=red}, name=p7
[x,red]
[y, red]
]
]
\draw [->, red](f1) to (p1);
\draw [->, red](f2) to (p2);
\draw [->, red](f3) to (p3);
\draw [->, red](f5) to (p6);
\draw [->, red](f6) to (p5);
\draw [->, red](f7) to (p7);
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]